# graph instagram get comments from posts

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to use the instagram graph api to get media comments. I followed the [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com) instruction, and the basic steps worked just fine!!

When I run:
[https://graph.instagram.com/:media-id?fields=id,caption,timestamp&access_token={{TOKEN}}](https://graph.instagram.com/:media-id?fields=id,caption,timestamp&access_token=%7B%7BTOKEN%7D%7D)

```
{
    "id": "17886788.....1695",
    "caption": "My test Post caption",
    "timestamp": "2023-10-13T14:54:00+0000"
}
```

From the documentation, at [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media). If I set comments_count at fields parameter or add /comments at request, I'll get the comments for the media. But it's not working.

When I run:
[https://graph.instagram.com/:id-media?fields=id,caption,comments_count&access_token={{TOKEN}}](https://graph.instagram.com/:id-media?fields=id,caption,comments_count&access_token=%7B%7BTOKEN%7D%7D)

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments_count) on node type (Media)",
        "type": "IGApiException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "ADdxjorTTYks2r-WacS91yn"
    }
}
```

When I run:
[https://graph.instagram.com/:id-media/comments?access_token={{TOKEN}}](https://graph.instagram.com/:id-media/comments?access_token=%7B%7BTOKEN%7D%7D)

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (Media)",
        "type": "IGApiException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "AtG_CT7PRqLe4aZ2AAQejs5"
    }
}
```

For the token, I've already added this scopes:

- user_profile
- user_media
- instagram_basic
- instagram_graph_user_profile
- instagram_graph_user_media
- instagram_manage_comments
- pages_show_list
- pages_read_engagement
- ads_management
- business_management

Anyone knows what I need to do to make it works?!

Answer (score 0):

Searching at developers.facebook.com community. I just found this post

https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2219648518091109/

It has the comment:

> "After your app has been approved, you can get the contract from your
> Business Manager. You need to do it on a Computer (mobile wont work)
> and have to be an Admin on the Business."

From your business Manager I just go to Business Info -> Business Contract (https://business.facebook.com/settings/info)

I'll reply if this real solve the problem, because the documentation, does not inform this needs